# unable to get selectedrow

Tags: java, swing

on form load my table is empty. When we select name from jcomboBox then details are load into table. Now I want to update the record. But unable to get selected row for update. getting error arrayIndexOutOfBound:-1 Plz help me to sort out this. Thanks in advance...

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;
class Credit extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private String value4="0";
    private String val="0";
    private String val1="0";
    private String jama="0",baki="0";
    private String nettdate="0",nettb="0",nettbal="0";
    private int row=0,count=0,aa=0,bb=0,t1=0;
    private String tj1="0",tb1="0",gt1="0";
    String h[]={"TID","Date","Jama","Baki","Nett"};
    private TableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();


        for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {

            columnNames.add(h[column]);

        }
            Vector<String> vector1 = new Vector<String>();
            Vector<String> vector2 = new Vector<String>();

        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        while (rs.next()) {


                Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();

                vector.add(rs.getString(1));
                vector.add(rs.getString(2));
                vector.add(rs.getString(3));
                vector.add(rs.getString(4));
                vector.add(rs.getString(5));
                count++;
            data.add(vector);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            aa=aa+Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            bb=bb+Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        }
        tj1=Integer.toString(aa);
        System.out.println("TJ:"+tj1);
        vector1.add("");
        vector1.add("Total");
        vector1.add(tj1);

        tb1=Integer.toString(bb);
        vector1.add(tb1);
        vector1.add("");
        System.out.println("h2:"+vector1);

        data.add(vector1);
        System.out.println("data:"+data);
        t1=Integer.parseInt(tb1)-Integer.parseInt(tj1);
        gt1=Integer.toString(t1);
        System.out.println("GT:"+gt1);

        vector2.add("");
        vector2.add("Nett Balance");
        vector2.add("");
        vector2.add(gt1);
        vector2.add("");
        data.add(vector2);
        System.out.println("data1:"+data);
        count=0;
        aa=0;
        bb=0;
        t1=0;
        tj1="0";
        tb1="0";
        gt1="0";

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 15);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton add,cancel,show,search,print,update,delete,net;
    JTextField jTextField,jTextField1,jTextField2,jTextField3,jTextField4,jTextField5;
    JComboBox jComboBox;
    String date,paid,total,s2,s3,s6,unpaid,mobile,city,nett,s4,s5,u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,accountno,tupdate;
    String Select[]={"Select"};
    Object name,s1;
    String an="0",nam="0",mono="0",cit="0";
    int token=0,tid=1,a,stid=0;
    JFrame f;
    AbstractAction action;
    private String id;
    Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
                        JPanel tablePanel;
                        DefaultTableModel model;
                        DefaultTableModel model1;
                        JTable table,table3;
  private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
  private Vector<Vector<String>> data1; //used for data from database
    private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
    private Vector<String> header2; //used to store data header
    private Vector<String> header3;
    private Vector<String> header4;
    private JLabel jlab4,jlab5,jlab6,jlab7;

    Credit(JFrame frm){
        Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image img=tk.getImage("1.jpg");
    setIconImage(img);
        JPanel creditPanel = createPanel1("Customer Credit & Debit Amount");
        tablePanel = createPanel2("Customer Credit & Debit Table");
        creditPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        tablePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.add(creditPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainPanel.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        creditPanel.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frm.add(mainPanel);
}
    private JPanel createPanel2(String title){
        tablePanel=new JPanel();
        tablePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tablePanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        header = new Vector<String>();
        header.add("TID"); 
        header.add("Date"); 
        header.add("Jama"); 
        header.add("Baki"); 
        header.add("Nett"); 
        header4 = new Vector<String>();
        header4.add("A/C No."); 
        header4.add("Name"); 
        header4.add("Mobile"); 
        header4.add("City"); 
        model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
        model1=new DefaultTableModel(data1,header4);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table3 = new JTable(model1);
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
        JScrollPane scroll1=new JScrollPane(table3);
        scroll1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,63));
        tablePanel.add(scroll1);
        tablePanel.add(scroll);

        JPanel p3=new JPanel();
        update=new JButton("Update");
        update.setFont(BTN_FONT);
        update.addActionListener(this);
        p3.add(update);
        tablePanel.add(p3);
        tablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return tablePanel;
    }
    private JPanel createPanel1(String title) {
        JPanel addUnitPanel = new JPanel();
        addUnitPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1, GAP, GAP));
        JLabel jlab4=new JLabel("Account No.:");
        jTextField4=new JTextField();
        jlab4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
        jTextField4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
        JLabel jlab5=new JLabel("Nett:");
        jTextField5=new JTextField();
        jlab5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(38,10));
        jTextField5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));

        JLabel jlab=new JLabel("Name:");
        jComboBox=new JComboBox(Select);//Select
        jlab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
        jComboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
        JLabel jlab1=new JLabel("Date:");
        jTextField1=new JTextField();
        jlab1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
        jTextField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
        JLabel jlab2=new JLabel("Jama:");
        jTextField2=new JTextField();
        jlab2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
        jTextField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
        JLabel jlab3=new JLabel("Baki:");
        jTextField3=new JTextField();
        jlab3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,10));
        jTextField3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));

        String m[]={"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
        String m1[]={"00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    jTextField1.setText(m1[cal.get(Calendar.DATE)]+"/"+m[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            private int b=0,a=0;
            private String tj="0";
            private String tb="0";
            private int t=0;
            private String gt="0";


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try
        {
            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    Object name=jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
            st=con.createStatement();

            rs= st.executeQuery("select AccountNo,Unpaid from Debit where Name='"+name+"'");
                     while(rs.next())
            {
                jTextField4.setText(rs.getString(1));
                                jTextField5.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                model.setRowCount(0);
                                model1.setRowCount(0);
                                b=0;
                                a=0;
                                tj="0";
                                tb="0";
                                t=0;
                                gt="0";
                                an="0";nam="0";mono="0";cit="0";

                                data=getJamaCustomer(name);
                                data1=getIdName(name);
        Object[] d3={data1.get(0).get(0),data1.get(0).get(1),data1.get(0).get(3),data1.get(0).get(4)};
        model1.addRow(d3);

        JTable table1=new JTable(data,header);
        for(int i=0;i<table1.getRowCount();i++){
        Object[] d={data.get(i).get(0),data.get(i).get(1),data.get(i).get(2),data.get(i).get(3),data.get(i).get(4)};
        model.addRow(d);

        }
        for(int i=0;i<table1.getRowCount();i++){
            a=a+Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(2));

            b=b+Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(3));
        }
        tj=Integer.toString(a);
        tb=Integer.toString(b);
        Object[] d1={"","Total",tj,tb,""};
        model.addRow(d1);



        t=Integer.parseInt(tb)-Integer.parseInt(tj);
        gt=Integer.toString(t);
        Object[] d2={"","Nett Balance","",gt,""};
        model.addRow(d2);

        table = new JTable(model);
        table3 = new JTable(model1);


        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table3.setRowHeight(30);
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
        JScrollPane scroll1=new JScrollPane(table3);
        tablePanel.add(scroll1);
        tablePanel.add(scroll);
                        }
            rs.close();
                        st.close();
                        con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("GG"+e);
        }

        }

            private Vector<Vector<String>> getJamaCustomer(Object name) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
              Vector<Vector<String>> jamacustomerVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"

PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Credit where Name='"+name+"' order by TID");
ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();//

while(rs.next())
{
Vector<String> jamacustomer = new Vector<String>();
jamacustomer.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
jamacustomer.add(rs.getString(4)); //Empid
jamacustomer.add(rs.getString(5)); //Empid
jamacustomer.add(rs.getString(6)); //Empid
jamacustomer.add(rs.getString(7)); //Empid
jamacustomerVector.add(jamacustomer);

}
/*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();

return jamacustomerVector;
            }

            private Vector<Vector<String>> getIdName(Object name) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
Vector<Vector<String>> idnameVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
//String myDB ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=pay.MDB";
String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                //userID = "Admin";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"


//Connection conn = dbConnection();
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select * from ManageCustomer where Name='"+name+"'");
ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();//

while(rs.next())
{
Vector<String> idname = new Vector<String>();
idname.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
idname.add(rs.getString(2)); //Empid
idname.add(rs.getString(3)); //Empid
idname.add(rs.getString(4)); //Empid
idname.add(rs.getString(5)); //Empid
idnameVector.add(idname);

}
/*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();

return idnameVector;
//                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
            }
        });
        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        p1.add(jlab); 
        p1.add(jComboBox);
        addUnitPanel.add(p1);
        loadcombo2();

        addUnitPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return addUnitPanel;
    } 


    void loadcombo2()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
                       // ResultSet rs1=null;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                //userID = "Admin";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    //sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUserProfile";
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
                    //con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:shop","system","manager"); 
            st=con.createStatement();

            rs= st.executeQuery("select distinct(Name) from ManageCustomer");
            //rs1=st.executeQuery("select Unit from AddUnit");
                        while(rs.next())
            {
                jComboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));
                                //jComboBox1.addItem(rs1.getString(1));
            }
            rs.close();
                       // rs1.close();
                        st.close();
                        con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("GG"+e);
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
if(ae.getSource()==update){
       int row = table.getSelectedRow();
if (row != -1) {
   row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
   String value = (String) model.getValueAt(row, 0);
   System.out.println("value:"+value);
           }
            int n=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainPanel, "Would you like to update the record?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        try{   


            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            ResultSet rs1=null;
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                //userID = "Admin";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    //sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUserProfile";
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
                    //con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:shop");
                    st=con.createStatement();
                    System.out.println("table.getValueAt(row,0)"+table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Credit where TID="+table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                    if(rs.next()){
                        s1=rs.getString(1);
                        s2=rs.getString(2);//accounno
                        s3=rs.getString(3);//name
                        s4=rs.getString(4);
                        s5=rs.getString(5);//paid
                        s6=rs.getString(6);//unpaid
                    }
                PreparedStatement smt=con.prepareStatement("select * from Debit where Name=?");
                smt.setObject(1, s3);
                rs=smt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    u1=rs.getString(1);
                    u2=rs.getString(2);
                    u3=rs.getString(3);
                    u4=rs.getString(4);
                    u5=rs.getString(5);
                    u6=rs.getString(6);//unpaid

                }

                st.executeUpdate("delete from Credit where TID="+table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                System.out.println("Deleted");
                st.executeUpdate("delete from Debit where Name='"+s3+"'");
                tid=Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row,0).toString());
                //s2
                //s3
                date=table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
                jama=table.getValueAt(row, 2).toString();//s5
                baki=table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString();//s6
                nett=table.getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
                 rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from NettDate where Name='"+s3+"'");
                 while(rs1.next()){
                     nettdate=rs1.getString(2);
                     nettbal=rs1.getString(3);
                 }
                String tpaid=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(s5)-Integer.parseInt(jama));
                String tunpaid=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(s6)-Integer.parseInt(baki));

                if(u6.contains("-")){
                    System.out.println("Contains -");
                if(tpaid.contains("-")&tunpaid.contains("-")){
                  tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                 nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                  System.out.println("1-"+tupdate);
              }else if(!tpaid.contains("-")&tunpaid.contains("-")){
                tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                 nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("2-"+tupdate);}
              else if(tpaid.contains("-")&!tunpaid.contains("-")){
                    tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
               nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("3-"+tupdate);
                }else{
                    tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
               nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("4-"+tupdate);
                }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Not Contains -");
                if(tpaid.contains("-")&tunpaid.contains("-")){
                  tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                 nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                  System.out.println("1"+tupdate);
              }else if(!tpaid.contains("-")&tunpaid.contains("-")){
                tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                 nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("2"+tupdate);}
              else if(tpaid.contains("-")&!tunpaid.contains("-")){
                    tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
               nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("3"+tupdate);
                }else{
                    tupdate=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(u6)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
               nettb=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(nettbal)+Integer.parseInt(tpaid)-Integer.parseInt(tunpaid));
                System.out.println("4"+tupdate);
                }    
                }
                int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into Credit values("+tid+",'"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+date+"','"+jama+"','"+baki+"','"+nett+"')");
                st.executeUpdate("insert into Debit values('"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+u3+"','"+u4+"','"+date+"','"+tupdate+"')");
                if(Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row, 4).toString())==1){
                   st.executeUpdate("delete from NettDate where Name='"+s3+"'");

                    st.executeUpdate("insert into NettDate values('"+s3+"','"+date+"','"+nettb+"')");
                }
                if(i==0){
                    String msg="Record not updated Successfully";
                    String ss="Sorry..........";
                    int res=JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null,msg,ss,res);
                }else{
                    String msg="Record updated Successfully";
                    String ss="Congratlations..........";
                    int res=JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null,msg,ss,res);
                    //dispose();
                }

            rs=st.executeQuery("select TID,Date,Paid,Unpaid,Nett from Credit where Name='"+s3+"' order by Date");
            st.close();
            rs.close();
            rs1.close();
                con.close();

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ManageCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }catch(Exception err){ 
                    System.out.println("GG"+err);
                }
    } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        try {
            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
                       // ResultSet rs1=null;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/Program Files/Shop/shop.accdb";
                                //userID = "Admin";
                                password = "3064101991";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                            "Pwd="+password+";";
                    //sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUserProfile";
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
                    st = con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("select TID,Date,Paid,Unpaid,Nett from Credit where Name='"+s3+"' order by Date");
            table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
            con.close();
            //pstmt.close();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                              "You choose not to update the data !");

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException err) {
            // System.out.println(e);
            err.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}   }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frm=new JFrame("Customer Jama Baki");
        Credit b=new Credit(frm);
        //frm.setSize(650, 236);
        frm.setSize(650, 700);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setResizable(false);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please remove all code that is not relevant? I copied and pasted this into my IDE but I have to spend so much time figuring out the compile errors.

Comment: Sir Oliver Watkins  You want the whole code?

Comment: Should I edit it to my whole code?

Comment: something that is runnable. Ideally you should cut and cut and cut, until you are left with only the problem. That way we can work faster.

Comment: can you provide double Vector test code for JamaCUstomer and getIdName (line 352)? That way i dont have to use the DBEngine.

Comment: i still see DBEngine in there. My code doesnt compile

Comment: can you provide me with dummy code for dbengine.getJamaCustomer(name); and dbengine.getIdNname(name);

Comment: Try to add proper code...!! meanwhile you can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Sir Plz see the edited code this is runnable

Comment: Sir have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just removed the following lines of code from the `jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ ... });`

What I am doing is, adding `model` to `table` two times that why it is not getting the selected row. After removing following lines of code it works fine.

```
    table = new JTable(model);
    table3 = new JTable(model1);


    table.setRowHeight(30);
    table3.setRowHeight(30);
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
    JScrollPane scroll1=new JScrollPane(table3);
    tablePanel.add(scroll1);
    tablePanel.add(scroll);
```

Comment: Can you distill this large piece of code to just the changes you've made to get it working? The way it's presented now isn't helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like nothing is selected in your table. You can check whether it's really selected. If not use for example the first row in the table or just ignore the update.

Comment: When we set row=0 it works... But not for row=table.getSelectedRow();

Comment: yes thats because no tableview cell is selected. then selectedRow will return -1. And -1 is an invalid index.

Answer (score 1):

```
int selection = table.getSelectedRow();    

if(selection == -1) {
    row = 0;
    }
    else row = selection;
```

Based on the comments below you might want to add a ListSelectionListener to your table.

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MySelectionListener(table) {
     @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                 System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: But what to do when our selected row number is other than zero?

Comment: then it gets set via row = selection;

Comment: Suppose the situation when we select last row of the table then how to get selectedrow. getSelectedRow() method returns -1 for all the selections.

Comment: ok this is not normal behaviour. it should return only -1 if there is no row selected. please try to add a listselectionlistener (See my edited answer)